# Regarding tree view, is it possible to have a search function?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I will like to know if it's possible to have a search bar to search for a particular node value and hence only show the branches that consist of the search value?

I did a sample codepen.
https://codepen.io/itealeaf/pen/vYLyVNp?editors=1111

```
function searchFunction() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  let value = input.value;
  var chartInstance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(document.getElementById("main"));
  //logic for displaying branch of search value
  let options = chartInstance.getOption()
  let series = options.series
  let data2 = series[0].data
  //console.log(data2[0])
  data2[0].children[1].collapsed = false
  data2[0].children[1].children[0].collapsed = false
  //console.log(data2[0].children)
  //console.log("AA", data2[0].children[1].children[0])
  chartInstance.setOption({
    series: [
       {
           data: data2
       }
   ]
  })
}
```

Ok, so i kind of figure out how to toggle collapse the tree branch. Just wondering if there is any simpler way?

Comment: Please provide sample and your try

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite simple but possible. Two months ago I wrote the solution for paint (sub)branch by click on node, you task is very similar: you need detect the target node (which contains search term) and then iterate to top (in my example to down) for find branch root and then to hide branches that are not child for target node branch.

Take a look: [Is there an ECharts option for coloring or highlight tree branch when I clicked a specific node and draw a path up to their children leaves?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61332631/is-there-an-echarts-option-for-coloring-or-highlight-tree-branch-when-i-clicked/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but first, you need to get the value of the search result(input element value), after that you [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it with value, and set the `series` of the graph. I coded a basic example of this, but it is not the whole answer, you need to go into it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-brook-fl0m7?file=/src/App.js